# Limit the Properties Bound to DataGrid in WPF using MVVM

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm, binding, datagrid

All, a simple question. I have a MVVM application with a `DataGrid` which I have bound to a ViewModel using

```
<DataGrid ItemsSource="{Binding Path=Resources}" ...></DataGrid>
```

where the `Resources` is defined via

```
public ObservableCollection<ResourceViewModel> Resources { get; private set; }
```

In the `ResourceViewModel` class however, I not only have properties that I want to appear in the `DataGrid`, but other properties that I *do not* want to appear in the `DataGrid`. The `ResourceViewmodel` class is

```
public class ResourceViewModel : WorkspaceViewModel, IDataErrorInfo
{
    readonly Resource resource;
    readonly ResourceDataRepository resourceRepository;
    private bool isSelected;

    public ResourceViewModel(Resource resource, ResourceDataRepository resourceRepository)
    {
        if (resource == null)
            throw new ArgumentNullException("resource");
        if (resourceRepository == null)
            throw new ArgumentNullException("resourceRepository");
        this.resource = resource;
        this.resourceRepository = resourceRepository;
    }

    public string KeyIndex 
    { 
        get { return this.resource.KeyIndex; } 
        set 
        {
            if (value == this.resource.KeyIndex)
                return;
            this.resource.KeyIndex = value;
            base.OnPropertyChanged("KeyIndex");
        }
    }

    public string FileName
    {
        get { return this.resource.FileName; }
        set 
        {
            if (value == this.resource.FileName)
                return;
            this.resource.FileName = value;
            base.OnPropertyChanged("FileName");
        }
    }

    public List<string> ResourceStringList
    {
        get { return this.resource.ResourceStringList; }
        set 
        {
            if (Utilities.Utilities.ScrambledEquals<string>(this.resource.ResourceStringList, value))
                return;
            this.resource.ResourceStringList = value;
            base.OnPropertyChanged("ResourceStringList");
        }
    }

    public bool IsSelected
    {
        get { return isSelected; }
        set
        {
            if (value == isSelected)
                return;
            isSelected = value;
            base.OnPropertyChanged("IsSelected");
        }
    }
}
```

Where I don't want `IsSelected` to appear in the `DataGrid` and I want each item in `ResourceStringList` to appear in a different column of the `Datagrid`. My questions are:

**1. How do I prevent `IsSelected` from showing [as a `Checkbox`] in the `DataGrid`?**

**2. How do I get the binding to the `DataGrid` to automatically display items in separate columns?**

*What have you tried:*

1. I have attempted to inherit from the `ResourceViewmodel` class and bind to this instead, but this is disgusting and I would like another more elegant solution; please :].
2. I have no idea how to proceed with this one. The number of items stored in the `List` is variable and set at runtime - so this needs to be a `List`.

As always, thanks very much for your time.

Comment: You could create your own columns manually. See [DataGrid.AutoGenerateColumns](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.datagrid.autogeneratecolumns.aspx) for more info.

Comment: If number of items in ResourceStringList is different for each row how many columns you want to generate and what should be their header?

Comment: im always confused when People use ObservableCollection in a MVVM pattern. i thought it is not neccesary if you use MVVM... and i really never needed it because there was always a solution without it. :/

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think the options are to turn off auto generation as Silvermind mentioned (i.e. setting DataGrid.AutoGenerateColumns to false and then defining the columns) or implement ITypedList. For example you could create a derived ObservableCollection that implements ITypedList and returns properties based on some attribute you put on the properties you want to hide.

```
public partial class MainWindow : Window
{
    public MainWindow()
    {
        this.DataContext = new TypedListObservableCollection<Foo>();

        InitializeComponent();
    }
}

public class TypedListObservableCollection<T> : ObservableCollection<T>
    , ITypedList
{
    public TypedListObservableCollection()
    {
    }

    PropertyDescriptorCollection ITypedList.GetItemProperties(PropertyDescriptor[] listAccessors)
    {
        return TypeDescriptor.GetProperties(typeof(T), new Attribute[] { BrowsableAttribute.Yes });
    }

    string ITypedList.GetListName(PropertyDescriptor[] listAccessors)
    {
        return typeof(T).Name;
    }
}

public class Foo
{
    public string Name
    {
        get;
        set;
    }

    [Browsable(false)]
    public bool IsSelected
    {
        get;
        set;
    }
}
```

Comment: +1 thanks for your help. Could you offer any advice on how I can populate the `DataGrid` columns with entries from my `List<string> ResourceStringList` because at the moment the `DataGrid` is just showing a single column with '(Collection)'. Someone mentioned that what header would the column obtained from a `List<string>` get: is there someway to also provide this? Thanks very much for your time...

Comment: Well as @LPL pointed out how do you know how many columns to provide if the ResourceStringList at least in theory could have a different number of items per data item and the columns have to be defined for all the items? If you know the max # of items and want to generate a column for each then in theory you could create a derived PropertyDescriptor that represents each column and return those in the PropertyDescriptorCollection returned from the GetItemProperties.

Comment: I don't know if the DataGrid responds when columns are added/removed but if so and you need that then you need to write your own custom IBindingList implementation and raise the ListChanged when columns are added/removed.

Comment: I have been away. Just implementing your answer now. I have now got my `public TypedListObservableCollection<ResourceDataViewModel> Resources { get; private set; }` accessor which I bind to the `DataGrid`. However, before it was an `ObservableCollection` and I added items to the `Resources` via: `this.Resources = new ObservableCollection<ResourceViewModel>(resViewModelList);` but now what do I do to add to the `TypedListObservableCollection`?

Comment: @Killercam, I don't understand the question. TypedListObservableCollection<T> simply derives from ObservableCollection<T> so it can be used exactly as you had used OC<T> because it is a OC<T>.

Answer (score 2):

To me its just easier not auto generate columns. But that's a personal preference, so I think the easiest way to not allow some properties to be exposed is to use the power of interfaces :)

1. Bind to ObservableCollection of IResourceViewModel  - make  Resources property a list of interface instead of a concrete type
2. make ResourceViewModel implement IResourceViewModel
3. in IResourceViewModel remove the properties that you don't want to be visible to the grid from the interface

Comment: While that would limit the properties it would also mean you wouldn't get automatic add new capability (assuming you want that of course) since the T would not be a creatable type so you would have to use BindingList<T> and handle the AddingNew or implement IEditableCollectionView or IBindingList yourself.

Comment: true (to a point - to make things work out of the box) and that's why I gave +1 to your aproach before posting mine. Yet, having an Add command and handling 
List operations in the view model would do the trick as well